# Posix sleep(), usleep() and nanosleep() don't work but Sleep() does under cygwin gcc

Tags: sleep

When I use sleep, usleep or nanosleep, the test program seems to have no delay at all (I was trying 10 seconds), but when I use the windows Sleep() function, it delays correctly.
What am I missing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using `sleep`, `usleep`, and `nanosleep` in cygwin?

Comment: I tried to, as my post states, but they don't seem to work. Why do you ask?